# Prepend to Gmaps directions element

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, prepend

I'm using the Google Maps JavaScript API and I would like to prepend the phrase "Starting From" to the ".adp-placemark" class that is included in the directions output by Google:

```
$('.adp-placemark').prepend('Starting From:');
```

The prepend is not working. However, if I view the page and use the Console tool in Inspector and then run the above code it will prepend as it should.

Where do I place this code? I've also tried placing it in a separate function and inside document ready.

```js
function initMap() {
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 7,
    center: {lat: 41.85, lng: -87.65}
  });
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('right-panel'));

  var control = document.getElementById('floating-panel');
  control.style.display = 'block';
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(control);

  var onChangeHandler = function() {
    calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
  };
  document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
  document.getElementById('end').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
}

function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
  var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
  var end = document.getElementById('end').value;
  directionsService.route({
    origin: start,
    destination: end,
    travelMode: 'DRIVING'
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status === 'OK') {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      $('.adp-placemark').prepend('Starting From:');
    } else {
      window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
#floating-panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 25%;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
#right-panel {
  font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

#right-panel select, #right-panel input {
  font-size: 15px;
}

#right-panel select {
  width: 100%;
}

#right-panel i {
  font-size: 12px;
}
#right-panel {
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
  width: 390px;
  overflow: auto;
}
#map {
  margin-right: 400px;
}
#floating-panel {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Arial;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.4);
  display: none;
}
@media print {
  #map {
    height: 500px;
    margin: 0;
  }
  #right-panel {
    float: none;
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="floating-panel">
  <strong>Start:</strong>
  <select id="start">
    <option value="chicago, il">Chicago</option>
    <option value="st louis, mo">St Louis</option>
    <option value="joplin, mo">Joplin, MO</option>
    <option value="oklahoma city, ok">Oklahoma City</option>
    <option value="amarillo, tx">Amarillo</option>
    <option value="gallup, nm">Gallup, NM</option>
    <option value="flagstaff, az">Flagstaff, AZ</option>
    <option value="winona, az">Winona</option>
    <option value="kingman, az">Kingman</option>
    <option value="barstow, ca">Barstow</option>
    <option value="san bernardino, ca">San Bernardino</option>
    <option value="los angeles, ca">Los Angeles</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <strong>End:</strong>
  <select id="end">
    <option value="chicago, il">Chicago</option>
    <option value="st louis, mo">St Louis</option>
    <option value="joplin, mo">Joplin, MO</option>
    <option value="oklahoma city, ok">Oklahoma City</option>
    <option value="amarillo, tx">Amarillo</option>
    <option value="gallup, nm">Gallup, NM</option>
    <option value="flagstaff, az">Flagstaff, AZ</option>
    <option value="winona, az">Winona</option>
    <option value="kingman, az">Kingman</option>
    <option value="barstow, ca">Barstow</option>
    <option value="san bernardino, ca">San Bernardino</option>
    <option value="los angeles, ca">Los Angeles</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="right-panel"></div>
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Comment: `.adp-placemark` is this class getting generated by google map API? Can you create the fiddle for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** As mentioned in the comments the first solution was incomplete as the 'Starting from:' was added to both tables (which I missed the first time)

In order to solve it using only CSS you could add `nth-child(n)` selectors to find the `.adp-placemark` you with to include the prepended text, like so:

```
    /* Pseudo-element to add 'Starting from:' to the first element that appears */
    .adp > div:nth-child(2) .adp-placemark::before {
      content: 'Starting from:';
      white-space: nowrap;
    }

    /* Pseudo-element to add 'Going to:' to the second element that appears */
    .adp > div:nth-child(3) .adp-placemark::before {
        content: 'Going to:';
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
```

**On the other hand** since the `right-panel` code is been generated by the Google Maps Api I wouldn't attempt to programatically change the generated HTML, because eventually the API may provide a different structure, which would make the solution to fail (been the solution in `js` or `css`).

---

One way to go about solving this **issue** would be to include a css pseudo-class to the `.adp-placemark`, removing the need to get the **timing** of the table rendering right, like so:

```
.adp-placemark::before {
    content: 'Starting from:';
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

I've also updated your snippet:

```js
function initMap() {
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 7,
    center: {lat: 41.85, lng: -87.65}
  });
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('right-panel'));

  var control = document.getElementById('floating-panel');
  control.style.display = 'block';
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(control);

  var onChangeHandler = function() {
    calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
  };
  document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
  document.getElementById('end').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
}

function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
  var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
  var end = document.getElementById('end').value;
  directionsService.route({
    origin: start,
    destination: end,
    travelMode: 'DRIVING'
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status === 'OK') {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      $('.adp-placemark').prepend('Starting From:');
    } else {
      window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
#floating-panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 25%;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
#right-panel {
  font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

#right-panel select, #right-panel input {
  font-size: 15px;
}

#right-panel select {
  width: 100%;
}

#right-panel i {
  font-size: 12px;
}
#right-panel {
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
  width: 390px;
  overflow: auto;
}
#map {
  margin-right: 400px;
}
#floating-panel {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Arial;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.4);
  display: none;
}

/* Pseudo-element to add 'Starting from:' to the first element that appears */
.adp > div:nth-child(2) .adp-placemark::before {
  content: 'Starting from:';
  white-space: nowrap;
}

/* Pseudo-element to add 'Going to:' to the second element that appears */
.adp > div:nth-child(3) .adp-placemark::before {
    content: 'Going to:';
    white-space: nowrap;
}


@media print {
  #map {
    height: 500px;
    margin: 0;
  }
  #right-panel {
    float: none;
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="floating-panel">
  <strong>Start:</strong>
  <select id="start">
    <option value="chicago, il">Chicago</option>
    <option value="st louis, mo">St Louis</option>
    <option value="joplin, mo">Joplin, MO</option>
    <option value="oklahoma city, ok">Oklahoma City</option>
    <option value="amarillo, tx">Amarillo</option>
    <option value="gallup, nm">Gallup, NM</option>
    <option value="flagstaff, az">Flagstaff, AZ</option>
    <option value="winona, az">Winona</option>
    <option value="kingman, az">Kingman</option>
    <option value="barstow, ca">Barstow</option>
    <option value="san bernardino, ca">San Bernardino</option>
    <option value="los angeles, ca">Los Angeles</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <strong>End:</strong>
  <select id="end">
    <option value="chicago, il">Chicago</option>
    <option value="st louis, mo">St Louis</option>
    <option value="joplin, mo">Joplin, MO</option>
    <option value="oklahoma city, ok">Oklahoma City</option>
    <option value="amarillo, tx">Amarillo</option>
    <option value="gallup, nm">Gallup, NM</option>
    <option value="flagstaff, az">Flagstaff, AZ</option>
    <option value="winona, az">Winona</option>
    <option value="kingman, az">Kingman</option>
    <option value="barstow, ca">Barstow</option>
    <option value="san bernardino, ca">San Bernardino</option>
    <option value="los angeles, ca">Los Angeles</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="right-panel"></div>
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Hope it helps,
Cheers.

Comment: This would be a nice solution, but to expand my question... There is a starting address and ending address shown that both use the ".adp-placemark" class.. The first would say "Starting From" and the second would prepend "Ending At". Do you know how I can target the first and second separately? Thanks for your help

Comment: I see, actually on my phone now, can you check if this would work?  

#right-panel table.adp-placemark:first-child:before {
      content: 'Starting from:';
      white-space: nowrap;
    }

    #right-panel table.adp-placemark:last-child:before {
      content: 'Going to:';
      white-space: nowrap;
    }

Comment: I tried your suggestion above and it prepends all the .adp-placemark classes with "Going to".

Also it seems the .adp-placemark class can be targeted with nth-of-type(1) but it doesn't find any with nth-of-type(2)

Comment: @cpcdev I've updated my answer to solve the issue, it's a little trick in css to get the correct child of `.right-panel` via it's parent div instead the nested table.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to figure this out! Works great! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for the side panel to be rendered (the Google Maps Javascript API is event driven and asynchronous).  Adding a `setTimeout` around the prepend operation works (proves the concept, although it's kludgy):

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $('.adp-placemark').prepend('Starting From:');
}, 500);
```

(You also need to add jQuery to your code snippet for it to work...)
That causes the browser to delay the prepend operation until after the rendering of the side panel is complete.

```js
function initMap() {
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 7,
    center: {
      lat: 41.85,
      lng: -87.65
    }
  });
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('right-panel'));

  var control = document.getElementById('floating-panel');
  control.style.display = 'block';
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(control);

  var onChangeHandler = function() {
    calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
  };
  document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
  document.getElementById('end').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
}

function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
  var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
  var end = document.getElementById('end').value;
  directionsService.route({
    origin: start,
    destination: end,
    travelMode: 'DRIVING'
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status === 'OK') {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('.adp-placemark').prepend('Starting From:');
      }, 500);

    } else {
      window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
#floating-panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 25%;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'sans-serif';
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
#right-panel {
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'sans-serif';
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
#right-panel select,
#right-panel input {
  font-size: 15px;
}
#right-panel select {
  width: 100%;
}
#right-panel i {
  font-size: 12px;
}
#right-panel {
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
  width: 390px;
  overflow: auto;
}
#map {
  margin-right: 400px;
}
#floating-panel {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Arial;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.4);
  display: none;
}
@media print {
  #map {
    height: 500px;
    margin: 0;
  }
  #right-panel {
    float: none;
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="floating-panel">
  <strong>Start:</strong>
  <select id="start">
    <option value="chicago, il">Chicago</option>
    <option value="st louis, mo">St Louis</option>
    <option value="joplin, mo">Joplin, MO</option>
    <option value="oklahoma city, ok">Oklahoma City</option>
    <option value="amarillo, tx">Amarillo</option>
    <option value="gallup, nm">Gallup, NM</option>
    <option value="flagstaff, az">Flagstaff, AZ</option>
    <option value="winona, az">Winona</option>
    <option value="kingman, az">Kingman</option>
    <option value="barstow, ca">Barstow</option>
    <option value="san bernardino, ca">San Bernardino</option>
    <option value="los angeles, ca">Los Angeles</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <strong>End:</strong>
  <select id="end">
    <option value="chicago, il">Chicago</option>
    <option value="st louis, mo">St Louis</option>
    <option value="joplin, mo">Joplin, MO</option>
    <option value="oklahoma city, ok">Oklahoma City</option>
    <option value="amarillo, tx">Amarillo</option>
    <option value="gallup, nm">Gallup, NM</option>
    <option value="flagstaff, az">Flagstaff, AZ</option>
    <option value="winona, az">Winona</option>
    <option value="kingman, az">Kingman</option>
    <option value="barstow, ca">Barstow</option>
    <option value="san bernardino, ca">San Bernardino</option>
    <option value="los angeles, ca">Los Angeles</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="right-panel"></div>
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initMap">
</script>
```